# All browsers except IE7-IE8 via jQuery

Tags: jquery, browser, version

Just wondering how to target all browsers EXCEPT IE8 and below ?

I tried something like

`if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > "8.99") { }`

But i'm unclear how to get every other browser ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`if (!$.browser.msie || parseInt(&.browser.version) > 8) {}`

Comment: thanks @numbers - will this still target IE9 as your excluding msie ?

Comment: Test it but sure, it should.  First part is true if the browser is not msie, the 2nd part is true if the browser version is > 9.

Answer (score 0):

$.browser.msie is not supported in latest version of jquery you can either add jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js or use following jquery function... for IE it also gives you version ...

call currentBrowser().browser  to detect browser and currentBrowser().version for IE version .........

```
function currentBrowser() {

$.returnVal = "";

var browserUserAgent = navigator.userAgent;

if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Firefox" };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Chrome" };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Safari" };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {

    var splitUserAgent = browserUserAgent.split(";");

    for (var val in splitUserAgent) {

        if (splitUserAgent[val].match("MSIE")) {

            var IEVersion = parseInt(splitUserAgent[val].substr(5, splitUserAgent[val].length));
        }
    }

    $.returnVal = { browser: "IE", version: IEVersion };
}

else if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Opera") > -1) {

    $.returnVal = { browser: "Opera" };
}

else {
    $.returnVal =
     { browser: "other" };
}

return $.returnVal;
}
```